# Nullable Generic type for both ValueTypes and ReferenceTypes

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, nullable

Is there a way to define this

```
public class VarValueChangeEventArgs<T> : EventArgs  /* where T : struct */ /* where T: notnull */  {
    public T? PrevValue;
    public T NewValue;

    public VarValueChangeEventArgs(T? prevValue, T newValue) {
        this.PrevValue = prevValue;
        this.NewValue = newValue;
    }
}
public class Cat {}
```

so both of this will work?

```
//with ref types
new VarValueChangeEventArgs<Cat>(null, new()); //works when constraining T to notnull

//with value types
new VarValueChangeEventArgs<int>(null, new()); //works when constraining T struct
```

***why:***
i receive a generic "`VarValueChangeEventArgs<object>`" event, where `newValue` is an `object`.
I want specific classes to forward the event, unboxing the value to its expected runtime type.
this to relieve subscribers from the duty of type-casting and the relative exception handling.

```
class I_subscribe_to_an_int {

    public EventHandler<VarValueChangeEventArgs<int>> OnThisSpecificVarChange;

    public void init() {
        publisher.OnAllValuesChange += (object _, VarValueChangeEventArgs<object> evt) => {
            try {
                OnThisSpecificVarChange?.Invoke(this, new(
                    newValue: (int)evt.NewValue
                    /*prevValue:(int)evt.PrevValue   //this can be null*/
                ));
            }
            catch(InvalidCastException ex) {  /* do something class-specific here */}
        };
    }
}
```

As you can note by the commented out `/* where */` clauses i managed to have them work for either of them, but not both at the same time.

The top would also be able to "downcast" them again to `VarValueChangeEventArgs<object>` when needed, for example for shared logging methods that need to accept all of them

Comment: AFAIK you can't have both.